# How to get data from multiple tables that belong to fields that contain checkboxes?

Tags: sql

I have a project that makes me confused. I am creating a 2nd hand sale car page for a sealer. I have display and edit pages. In edit pages, user will insert a sale car record or edit an existing record. I mean Such a table:

```
RecordID    CARNAME    Model    Year    KM     PRICE
```

(This Part is ok, easy; but details of car will be showed and edited with checkboxes and also features must be editable)),

```
(Checkbox1) Airbag   (Checkbox2) Sunroof  (Checkbox 3) Xenon lamb  etc.
```

I think I must Create that tables:
Cars, Marks, Models, Features (includes checkboxes)...  But How will I get data from features; how will I know which check is checked or not and How will I know, which car has which features?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a table which lists features indexed by an integer:

FEATURES:

```
featurecode   feature
1             airbag
2             sunroof
3             headlights
.....
```

Then you have a table that lists features per REcordid with recordid as a foreign key:

RecordIDFeatures:

```
RecordID     Featurecode
23032        1
23032        2
23034        3
........
```

Then to get features per car you do:

```
selectt f.feature, s.car from features f, salesCarRecord s,RecordIDFeatures r where  (r.recordid = s.recordid) and (r.featurecode = f.featurecode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Features` table and then a `Features_Car` [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

```
Features Table
--------------

FeatureId | Name
----------------
1         | Sunroof
2         | Air Conditioning
3         | Power Steering

Features_Car Table
--------------

FeatureId | RecordId
----------------
1         | 1
2         | 1
3         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 2
1         | 3
3         | 3
```

Updating based on checkboxes in the UI will be straightforward, just `INSERT` or `DELETE` values from the junction table based on which checkboxes are checked or unchecked, respectively